# Migrating from ISAPI Rewrite to Mod_REwrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, coldfusion, isapi-rewrite

I'm currently using ISAPI Rewrite

I'd interesting in moving my ColdFusion app to Apache and would therefore like to use MOD_Rewrite. Is this possible? Or do I need to rewrite all the rewrites?

Comment: Most rules can be just transferred 1-to-1, barring a fews exceptions. Unless it's a very long list, I'd suggest you post your current rules for a more accurate & definitive answer.

Comment: And if it is a very long list, still post a handful of the rules (which are indicative of them all), and someone can explain any necessary changes, so you'll know how to migrate the rest. :)

Comment: How about this rule? RewriteRule /note-view/(\d+)/(.*) /notes/view/index.cfm\?noteID=$1 [I,L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mod Rewrite

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/(flex2gateway|jrunscripts|cfide|cfformgateway|railo-context|files|images|javascripts|miscellaneous|stylesheets|robots.txt|sitemap.xml|rewrite.cfm)($|/.*$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./rewrite.cfm/$1 [L]

ISAPI

RewriteRule (^/(flex2gateway|jrunscripts|cfide|cfformgateway|railo-context|files|images|javascripts|miscellaneous|stylesheets|robots.txt|sitemap.xml|rewrite.cfm)($|/.*$)) $1 [L,I]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /rewrite.cfm/$1 [L]

(Taking from ColdFusion on Wheels rewrite rules)

Comment: thanks. With ISAPI Rerewrite I simply add a httpd.ini file in the www root which contains all the rewrite rules and it just works. Is this possible with Apache? or do I need to modify some other existing Apache file?

Comment: you need to drop a .htaccess file in your www root